ZFS pool disappear after reboot
We have a ZFS system installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
Apparently, there was an electrical shutdown this week end, and when rebooting, the ZFS pool is no longer there.
zpool status -v gives : no pools available
zpool import -a gives: cannot import 'poolname': I/O error Destroy and re-create from a backup source.
zpool import -F gives all the info and says "state ONLINE", "The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier" so from that it seems it should work...
I cannot find any info online on what to do...
There is about 10 To of data on the disk, and we will need to retrieve it in a way or another...
